# Non Clustered Index performance effect on Update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with a dozen columns. There are non clustered, non unique index defined on 10 columns. Now using update statement i am updating some columns of my table based on some condition. Some of the columns that are getting updated have non clustered indexes.

Now deleting these non clustered index would optimize my update statement?

Comment: **Yes, of course!** Any index you have will need to be **maintained**, so it causes a bit of overhead for any operation (delete, insert, update)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, will good impact, but not sure how much.

http://dba.fyicenter.com/faq/sql_server/CREATE_INDEX_Impact_on_Other_User_Sessions.html

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50520/updating-an-indexed-column-performance-impact-in-sql-server

There is no ground rule to how much define non-clustered index in a table. Ideally 4 or 5 column is sufficient, but no rule to restict, every thing is depend on the database sized or say no. of record.

**Index is used while searching, but impact on insert and update.
The only thing to consider while assign index to columns(s), which are frequently used in the search.**

To avoid index, you can create a column of resulted or computed column (see links).

Means if you regularly need to calculate or sum of 2 columns to show inventroy, so good to create a column

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2011/11/28/a-computed-column-defined-with-a-user-defined-function-might-impact-query-performance.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19641/Computed-Column-Specification-in-SQL-Server